# Вывод в консоль в Visual Studio 2017

Tags: wpf, консоль, visual-studio-2017

Работаю над WPF-приложением. Использую консоль для вывода отладочной информации при работе приложения. Консоль подключаю через соответствующие методы из kernel.dll.
В Visual Studio 2012 все работало правильно. Недавно перешел на 17 версию студии и в ней данный вывод отсутствует. 
Как можно настроить вывод в консоль в Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: Зачем подключать из kernel, если стандартные средства прекрасно работают.

Comment: @ГеннадийП Создать консоль то надо, если приложение не консольное. Для этого и понадобится winapi-функция AllocConsole. Другое дело, зачем вообще консоль в WPF.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Я про то же, зачем нужна консоль для отладки, когда встроенная в студию все показывает.

Comment: Чтобы отслеживать нужные параметры не только с студии, но и при обычном запуске на другой машине.

Comment: Для отслеживания нужных параметров на другой машине используйте логи. Чтобы свой велосипед не городить, воспользуйтесь каким-нибудь из уже имеющихся, например, NLog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле консольный вывод, разумеется, никак не привязан к версии студии. Но многие методы класса Console, несмотря на название, выводят не в консоль, а в стандартный поток вывода, и никто не обещал, что он не будет перенаправлен. Так вот, в Visual Studio 2017 причина как будто именно в этом - при запуске под отладчиком стандартный вывод студия перенаправляет для каких-то своих целей.

Можно пересоздать stdout, так чтобы он выводил напрямую в консоль:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

#pragma warning disable CS0618

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool AllocConsole();

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern uint GetConsoleCP();

        const uint GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000;
        const uint GENERIC_WRITE = 0x40000000;
        const uint FILE_SHARE_READ = 0x00000001;
        const uint FILE_SHARE_WRITE = 0x00000002;
        const uint OPEN_EXISTING = 3;
        const uint FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL = 0x00000080;

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateFile(
             [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string filename,
             [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint access,
             [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint share,
             IntPtr securityAttributes,
             [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint creationDisposition,
             [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint flagsAndAttributes,
             IntPtr templateFile);

        public static bool CreateConsole()
        {
            bool res = AllocConsole(); //создаем консоль
            if (res == false) return false;

            uint cp = GetConsoleCP(); //получаем кодировку консоли

            //получаем дескриптор консоли
            var handle = CreateFile("CONOUT$", GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
            IntPtr.Zero, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, IntPtr.Zero);
            if (handle.ToInt64() == -1)
            {
                throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            }

            //Пересоздаем stdout
            Stream s = new FileStream(handle, FileAccess.Write);
            StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter( s, Encoding.GetEncoding((int)cp));
            wr.AutoFlush = true;
            System.Console.SetOut(wr);                        

            return true;
        }        

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            bool res = CreateConsole();
            if (res == false) MessageBox.Show("Failed to create console");

            Console.WriteLine("Hello from WPF!");
        }
    }    
}
```

Используйте на свой страх и риск, я понятия не имею, что может сломаться от подобных извращений. Вообще, непонятно зачем тут вообще нужна именно консоль: в ней нет ничего особенно удобного для целей отладки. Вы могли бы вместо этого использовать вывод в System.Diagnostics.Debug в отладочной конфигурации (`#if DEBUG`) и обычное окно с TextBox в релизной.

Comment: Спасибо Вам, добрый человек. Консоль нужна потому, что она уже настроена на вывод нужной информации. А также  потому, что там есть возможность с помощью цвета фона и текста делать лог более читаемый. Все это нужно только на этапе разработки, в готовом решении будет использоваться готовый логгер.

Comment: Данный метод работает, но нет изменения цвета текста и фона. Нужно использовать другой тип потока?

Comment: @ВиталийЕфимов В данном случае стандартные свойства типа BackgroundColor не будут работать. Для изменения цвета нужно будет использовать функцию SetConsoleTextAttribute, передавая ей дескриптор консоли, возвращенный CreateFile. Вот здесь есть пример и определения цветовых констант: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/coloring-the-console-in-C-Sharp/