# Вывод/чтение из консоли WinForms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, консоль

Столкнулся с проблемой. Приложение WinForms, хочу вывести некоторую информацию в консоль. Воспользовался таким решением:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool AllocConsole();

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AllocConsole();
    Console.WriteLine("Message!");
}
```

Консоль открывается, все как положено, но в нее ничего не выводится, также как и я ничего не могу через нее ввести. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Зачем консоль? Выводите в текстбокс.

Comment: попробуйте `private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    
    Console.WriteLine("Message!");
    Console.Read();
}`
Все остальное не нужно.

Comment: У вас случаем не вот эта проблема: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/890473/Вывод-в-консоль-в-visual-studio-2017

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, Очень похоже на то,большое спасибо!